# Only first part of paragraph being returned, up until child tag is encountered?

Tags: python, scrapy

This is using Scrapy.

I am encountering the following type of markup:

```html
<p>Noting the presence of a footnote<sup>1</sup> is one common way for superscripts to be used.</p>
```

Test page:
https://html.com/tags/sup/

Test query:

```py
response.css('div.render p::text')[0].extract()
```

Test ItemLoader:

```py
loader.add_css("text", "div.render p::text")
```

Test results:

> Noting the presence of a footnote

Test expected:

> Noting the presence of a footnote is one common way for superscripts to be used.

Question:

How can I get the full text of the paragraph, ignoring the child tag?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if scrapy has appropriate selector ignoring the nested `<sub>`. I suggest you to use `re` module in order to ignore the child. By the way this is not a solution in long run. You should not parse HTML using regex. For more information,please have a look at this thread [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Try this :

```
import re
def parse(self,response):
    extracted_p_tag=response.css('div.render p').get()
    ignored_sup=re.sub('<sup>(.*)</sup>','',extracted_p_tag)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll wait a while to see if any way appears that does not use regex